# tagging a custom tag for Django

Tags: python, django

Hello I'm doing my first project in django which is creating reddit clone. I'm not sure how I should set my model, especially setting tagging part. Like reddit, I want users to be able to tag to the community they created. I found many tagging app that enables you to tag to the categories admin made. But I want my users to tag to the categories they made.

```
class Post(models.Model):
       created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
       title = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
       content = models.TextField()
       url = models.URLField(max_length=250, blank=True)
       image = models.ImageField(upload_to="images", blank=True, null=True)
       views = models.IntegerField(dfault=0)
       likes = models.IntegerField(dfault=0)




class Category(models.Model): 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
```

Comment: can one post be associated with many categories?

Comment: Nope but the real problem I'm having is, When user makes a post how do I let a user to pick which tags(created by another users) they want to post?

Comment: You could use a MultipleChoiceField in the form.

Comment: I don't know if it helps, but this is very similar to the thing you are looking for.  https://github.com/alex/django-taggit

Comment: I'm sorry I meant to type no, i think it's better for post to be associated with one category. I was thinking to use foreignkey relationship what is mulltplechoice filed?  I googled it, kinda hard to understand

Comment: thanks kumar, that's the one I was looking for, not sure if I should use it or just foreignkey

Comment: @siyo updated my answer. So you need only one category per post?

Comment: yeah I think that will be better

Answer (score 0):

You should add a many-to-many relationship in your Post model

```
class Post(models.Model):
       created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
       title = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
       content = models.TextField()
       url = models.URLField(max_length=250, blank=True)
       image = models.ImageField(upload_to="images", blank=True, null=True)
       views = models.IntegerField(dfault=0)
       likes = models.IntegerField(dfault=0)
       # Add a m2m field named categories
       categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
```

This way you can get a list of all the associated categories with your post using -

```
post_object.categories.all()
```

For the form for adding the tags, you could use something as -

```
class TagForm(forms.Form):
    tags = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
                                 widget=forms.SelectMultiple,
                                 choices=tag_options,
                                 required=True)
```

where tag_options is a tuple of tuple containing the various tags obtained from `Category.objects.all()`

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was looking for. I saw some interesting soutions here, like https://github.com/alex/django-taggit....what;s your thought on this one/?

Comment: Its a good app. It really depends on what you are trying to achieve. If you are someone who is doing this to learn(as you mentioned), IMHO you should try to implement the maximum things on your own, instead of relying too much on third party apps. This will help you learn faster.

Comment: thank you, I guess I shoudn't use third party app yet. by the way, if I want one post per one category I should use foreignkey instead of many to many right?

Comment: Yes, foreign key instead of m2m

Comment: @siyo could you please accept the answer if your problem is solved?

Comment: Hi I think i did, it says thanks for your feedback your score will be displayed once i earn 15 points. plz let me know if i did it wrong

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding what you need is to understand Many2Many relation.
A post can has many categories and A category will have many posts.

```
categories = models.ManyToManyField(
    Category)
```

For further reading [read this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/).. :)

Comment: Pardon my English, I meant one post to one category. I should use Foreignkey right? Then I just saw this, https://github.com/alex/django-taggit   Which one do you think I should do?

Comment: Hi Si yo, as you see the documentation, there you will notice, apple (Food) has many tags (apple.tags.all() and you can see there are 3 instances). And each tag can be part of many foods. Here I would suggest you to use django-taggit as it is for many2many and you can easily integrate that. Coming back to one post - one category, that's not a good db design. My suggestions will be to use django-taggit. Good Luck.. :)